# Scala - Spark sql row pattern matching on struct

Tags: scala, apache-spark, struct, pattern-matching, case-class

I'm trying to do pattern matching inside a Dataframe map function - matching a Row with a Row pattern having a nested Case Class. This dataframe is a result of a join, and has the schema shown below. It has some columns of primitive types, and 2 compound columns:

```
case class MyList(values: Seq[Integer])
case class MyItem(key1: String, key2: String, field1: Integer, group1: MyList, group2: MyList, field2: Integer)
val myLine1 = new MyItem ("MyKey01", "MyKey02", 1, new MyList(Seq(1)), new MyList(Seq(2)), 2)
val myLine2 = new MyItem ("YourKey01", "YourKey02", 2, new MyList(Seq(2,3)), new MyList(Seq(4,5)), 20)
val dfRaw = Seq(myLine1, myLine2).toDF
dfRaw.printSchema
dfRaw.show
val df2 = dfRaw.map(r => r match {
    case Row(key1: String, key2: String, field1: Integer, group1: MyList, group2: MyList, field2: Integer) => "Matched"
    case _ => "Un matched"
})
df2.show
```

My problem is, after that map function, all I got was "Un matched":

```
root
 |-- key1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- group1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- group2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- field2: integer (nullable = true)
+---------+---------+------+--------------------+--------------------+------+
|     key1|     key2|field1|              group1|              group2|field2|
+---------+---------+------+--------------------+--------------------+------+
|  MyKey01|  MyKey02|     1|   [WrappedArray(1)]|   [WrappedArray(2)]|     2|
|YourKey01|YourKey02|     2|[WrappedArray(2, 3)]|[WrappedArray(4, 5)]|    20|
+---------+---------+------+--------------------+--------------------+------+
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]
+----------+
|     value|
+----------+
|Un matched|
|Un matched|
+----------+
```

If I ignore those two struct columns in the case branch (replacing ***group1: MyList, group2: MyList*** with ***_, _***, then it works

```
case Row(key1: String, key2: String, field1: Integer, group1: MyList, group2: MyList, field2: Integer) => "Matched"
```

Could you please help on how to do pattern matching on that Case class?
Thanks!

Comment: Use `dfRaw.as[MyItem]` and replace `Row` with `MyItem` and your existing code should work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct` columns are treated as `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema` in spark

so you will have to *define match case* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions._
val df2 = dfRaw.map(r => r match {
    case Row(key1: String, key2: String, field1: Integer, group1: GenericRowWithSchema, group2: GenericRowWithSchema, field2: Integer) => "Matched"
    case _ => "Un matched"
})
```

And *defining match case with wild-card (_) works* because *Scala compiler implicitly evaluates `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema` as datatype*.

Defining *case as below should work too* as with the wild-card due to implicit evaluation

```
case Row(key1: String, key2: String, field1: Integer, group1, group2, field2: Integer) => "Matched"
```

Comment: Thank you Ramesh. That worked. However, now I will need to extract my Seq[Integer] from that GenericRowWithSchema. I'm searching for how to do this. If you can, please help as well. My purpose is that to store an ordered list which wouldnserve as a FIFO queue. Shiuld that be better if I store my list directly as an Array?

Comment: You should accept this answer as accepted and ask another question for that. But before you ask another question research whether the question is already asked and has an accepted answer or not. I shall help you if its not already answered

Comment: Sorry, I m browsing on my phone, and have not found how to accept the answer. Will do that right when I have access to desktop browser. Yes, I did try to search, and have not found a solution for that GenericRowWithSchema yet. Will keep searching

Comment: Yes thats how it should be. You should search for an answer to your problem and when you don't find one then only you should be asking for a question.

Comment: I'm using spark 2.1, and it seems there's no support for using Seq there yet. So until now I still not have a solution. Pattern matching with GenericRowWithSchema helps going to the correct case branch, but not able to help further.

Comment: isn't your question `Could you please help on how to do pattern matching on that Case class?`? Your pattern matching question is answered by this question. then how come you downvoted? You should ask another question for another problem.

Comment: what help do you want further?

Comment: Hi Ramesh,
Sorry, but I hadn't down-voted. Someone else I guess. And I did mark your answer as accepted.
Thanks for the help.
I'm still searching for a solution to extracting data from that Seq[Integer] in Spark 2.1

Comment: @Averell I had guessed that its not you who downvoted. :) good luck with your search. if you don't find an answer you can always ask another question ;)